# Adding extra data to an element

Tags: plugin-development, entries, custom-field

I know questions similar to this have been asked in the past. But I still don't feel like I am getting a full picture so feel there is benefit in asking it again.

I want to add extra data to a post after that post is saved. In Wordpress world this is called meta data. And can be achieved by simply calling `update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value);`  (*I'm not saying Wordpress is better I'm just giving context of where I am coming from.*)

I know how to hook into the 'entries.saveEntry' event in my plugin but I am unclear where to save this extra data or how.

The extra data is not to be seen by the user and will likely be removed and updated each time the post is updated.

Comment: I'm about 0% familiar with Wordpress. What exactly is the extra data you want to save? Typically I'd say it would go into a custom field.

Comment: Sorry been away - in this instance I am grabbing bible references parsed from the entry content and wanting to save it against the entry. Do I have to create a new field? How do I do that programmatically through the plugin? And how do I then attach it to the entry?